# 'No file endpoint configured.' when trying to use file client in azure storage using the emulator

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files, azure-storage-emulator

I am trying to use the FileClient for Azure Storage using the latest emulator (5.9) and am getting the following exception: `No file endpoint configured.`

Here is my code:

```
    if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true", out var account))
            _fileClient = account.CreateCloudFileClient();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The File service and SMB protocol service endpoints are not currently supported in the storage emulator, as of now the only endpoints currently supported to work with Storage emulator are as below:

```
Blob service: http://127.0.0.1:10000/<account-name>/<resource-path>
Queue service: http://127.0.0.1:10001/<account-name>/<resource-path>
Table service: http://127.0.0.1:10002/<account-name>/<resource-path>
```

More information can be found **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator)**.